# In one component I am initializing custom aggrid 3 times, but 1st one only initializing remaing 2 were not initializing

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I created one custom(shared) ag-grid for reusable pusrpose in my project, but if I initialize the custom ag-grid in one component, it is working fine. like

***example.html***

```
<html>

<body>
 <input type="text">
 <md-app-aggrid [columnDefs]="columnDefs1" [rowData]="rowData1" 
 (editEvent)="getData($event);" [pagination]="false" [enableSorting]="false"
 [enableColResize]="false"></md-app-aggrid>
</body>

</html>
```

But now i trying to initialize the custom ag-grid in one component 3 times for for different validation purpose.

***customaggrid.html***

```
<div *ngIf="gridId == 'aggrid1'">
 <div [ngStyle]="style">
   <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" #agGrid class="ag- 
    theme-blue" [rowData]="rowData" rowSelection="single"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [pagination]="pagination" 
    [enableSorting]="enableSorting" [enableColResize]="enableColResize"
    (input)="dataChange($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady1($event)" 
    (getSelectedRows)="getSelectedRows()" 
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
   </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="gridId == 'aggrid2'">
  <div [ngStyle]="style">
   <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" #agGrid2 class="ag- 
    theme-blue" [rowData]="rowData" rowSelection="single"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [pagination]="pagination" 
    [enableSorting]="enableSorting" [enableColResize]="enableColResize"
    (input)="dataChange($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady2($event)" 
    (getSelectedRows)="getSelectedRows()" 
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
   </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="gridId == 'aggrid3'">
  <div [ngStyle]="style">
   <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" #agGrid3 class="ag- 
    theme-blue" [rowData]="rowData" rowSelection="single"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [pagination]="pagination" 
    [enableSorting]="enableSorting" [enableColResize]="enableColResize"
    (input)="dataChange($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady3($event)" 
    (getSelectedRows)="getSelectedRows()" 
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
   </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
 </div>
```

***customaggrid.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from 
'@angular/core';
import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'md-app-aggrid2',
templateUrl: './app-aggrid2.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app-aggrid2.component.scss']
})
export class AppAggrid2Component implements OnInit {

 params2: any;
 params3: any;
 params1: any;
 style: { width: any; height: any; };
 public getRowNodeId: (data: any) => any;
 selectedDataString: any;
 public gridApi1;
 public gridApi2;
 public gridApi3;
 public gridColumnApi;
 // getting inputs from parent component
 @Input() columnDefs: any;
 // @Input() height: any;
 // @Input() width: any;
 @Input() pagination: any;
 @Input() enableSorting: any;
 @Input() enableColResize: any;
 @Input() rowData: any;
 @Input() gridLayout: any;
 @Input() gridId: any;
 // editing form using editevent in parent component
 @Output() editEvent = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() editEvent2 = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() editEvent3 = new EventEmitter();
 // removing data from array in parent component
 @Output() removeEvent = new EventEmitter();
 @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridNg2;
 @ViewChild('agGrid2') agGrid2: AgGridNg2;
 @ViewChild('agGrid3') agGrid3: AgGridNg2;
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {
  if (this.gridLayout === 'manageOrders1.1') {
  this.setWidthAndHeight('100%', '250px');
  } else if (this.gridLayout === 'manageOrders1.2') {
  this.setWidthAndHeight('100%', '150px');
  } else {
  this.setWidthAndHeight('100%', '150px');
 }
}
 setWidthAndHeight(width, height) {
  this.style = {
  width: width,
  height: height,
 };
}
// initilize the ag-grid
onGridReady1(params) {
this.params1 = params;
console.log('onGridReady1', params);
this.gridApi1 = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
onGridReady2(params) {
this.params2 = params;
console.log('onGridReady2', params);
this.gridApi2 = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
onGridReady3(params) {
this.params3 = params;
console.log('onGridReady3', params);
this.gridApi3 = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
// adding new row to the grid
 submit(obj, grid) {
   if (grid === 'aggrid2') {
   this.gridId = 'aggrid2';
   // this.onGridReady2(this.params2);
   this.editEvent2.emit('Ravi aggrid2');
   // const res1 = this.gridApi2.updateRowData({ add: [obj] });
   const res1 = this.agGrid2.api.updateRowData({ add: [obj] });
   } else if (grid === 'aggrid3') {
   this.gridId = 'aggrid3';
   this.editEvent3.emit('Ravi aggrid3');
   // const res1 = this.gridApi3.updateRowData({ add: [obj] });
   const res1 = this.agGrid3.api.updateRowData({ add: [obj] });
   } else {
   const res1 = this.gridApi1.updateRowData({ add: [obj] });
  }
  }
  // checking the action type from cellClicked event
  onCellClicked(e) {
    if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
     const actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute('data-action-type');
  switch (actionType) {
    case 'edit':
      // callback to edit method in ag-grid
      return this.onRowEdit(e);
    case 'remove':
      // callback to remove method in ag-grid
      return this.onRemoveSelected(e);
    case 'deleteAndSend':
      // callback to remove method in ag-grid
      return this.sendToTodaysGrid(e);
    default:
      // callback to remove method in ag-grid
      return this.getSelectedData(e);
    }
   }
  }
   // emits the data in editevent to callback parent component
     onRowEdit(e) {
       this.editEvent.emit(e.data);
    }
    // emits the removing data and remove the selected data in ag-grid
     onRemoveSelected(e) {
      this.removeEvent.emit(e.data);
     const selectedData = e.data;
     const res2 = this.gridApi1.updateRowData({ remove: [selectedData] });
     // alert('deleted successfully');
     }
    // update existing row in ag-grid by using index
   update(obj, index) {
  const rowNode = this.gridApi1.getRowNode(index);
  rowNode.setData(obj);
  }
  // emits the data in editevent to callback parent component
   getSelectedData(e) {
   console.log('2 getSelectedData successfully' + e.data);
   this.editEvent.emit(e.data);
   }
   sendToTodaysGrid(e) {
  //..
  }
 }
```

***Main.html***

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <span style="font-size: 16px"> Manage orders </span>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style=" border: 1px solid gray;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <md-app-search jsonType="Snomed" itemName="snomed_fsn" 
    (typeOfJson)="jsonType=$event;" 
    (afterSearchData)="selectedData($event);"
              [dataShow]='false'></md-app-search>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" checked 
     (click)="selectOption(r.value)" #r value="all">All
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" 
    (click)="selectOption(r1.value)" #r1 value="pre">Previous Orders
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px">
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              By&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
              <option value="" disabled selected></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              Type &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group">
              Lab Company &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <md-app-aggrid2 gridId="aggrid1" [columnDefs]="columnDefs1" 
    [rowData]="rowData1" gridLayout="manageOrders1.1" 
    (editEvent)="getData($event);"
      [pagination]="false" [enableSorting]="false" 
      [enableColResize]="false"></md-app-aggrid2>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" checked 
    (click)="todaysOrders(t.value)" #t value="today">Today's Orders
    <md-app-aggrid2 gridId="aggrid2" [columnDefs]="columnDefs2" 
    [rowData]="rowData2" gridLayout="manageOrders1.2" 
    (editEvent2)="getData2($event);"
      [pagination]="false" [enableSorting]="false" 
      [enableColResize]="false"></md-app-aggrid2>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" (click)="todaysOrders(f.value)" #f 
     value="future">Future Orders
    <span style=" padding-left: 255px">Order Date : </span>&nbsp;{{date | 
     date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
    <md-app-aggrid2 gridId="aggrid3" [columnDefs]="columnDefs3" 
       [rowData]="rowData3" gridLayout="manageOrders1.2" 
      (editEvent3)="getData3($event);"
      [pagination]="false" [enableSorting]="false" 
     [enableColResize]="false"></md-app-aggrid2>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

so if I click any row in 1st ag-grid, that row should be added in 2nd ag-grid. this is what i have to do. but if click 1st ag-grid, that row added in same(1st)   ag-grid only. the 2nd or 3rd ag-grid were not all initializing. please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different `[gridOptions]` along with grid identity `#Grid`.

***Update by*** [un.spike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4483102/un-spike):
You don't need to use hashtag binding `# + @ViewChild('...') ...;` if you have defined (GridReady) function for API reference binding.

***View:***

```
<ag-grid-angular
                style="width: 100%; height: 45%"
                #topGrid
                class="ag-theme-balham"
                [rowData]="rowData"
                [gridOptions]="topOptions"
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>

        <ag-grid-angular
                style="width: 100%; height: 45%"
                #bottomGrid
                class="ag-theme-balham"
                [rowData]="rowData"
                [gridOptions]="bottomOptions"
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

***Model:***

```
export class AppComponent {
    columnDefs;
    rowData;
    topOptions = {alignedGrids: []};
    bottomOptions = {alignedGrids: []};

    @ViewChild('topGrid') topGrid;
    @ViewChild('bottomGrid') bottomGrid;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.columnDefs = [
            {headerName: 'Athlete', field: 'athlete', width: 200},
            {headerName: 'Age', field: 'age', width: 150},
            {headerName: 'Country', field: 'country', width: 150},
            {headerName: 'Year', field: 'year', width: 120},
            {headerName: 'Date', field: 'date', width: 150},
            {headerName: 'Sport', field: 'sport', width: 150},
            {
                headerName: 'Medals',
                children: [
                    {
                        headerName: "Total", columnGroupShow: 'closed', field: "total",
                        valueGetter: "data.gold + data.silver + data.bronze", width: 200
                    },
                    {headerName: "Gold", columnGroupShow: 'open', field: "gold", width: 100},
                    {headerName: "Silver", columnGroupShow: 'open', field: "silver", width: 100},
                    {headerName: "Bronze", columnGroupShow: 'open', field: "bronze", width: 100}
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.topOptions.alignedGrids.push(this.bottomOptions);
        this.bottomOptions.alignedGrids.push(this.topOptions);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json').subscribe(data => {
            this.rowData = data;
        });
    }
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/), there is an angular example you can view it in [Plunker](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/#) as well.

Hope this helps.,

Comment: i don't want to add 2 or 3  ag-grids in my custom-ag-grid.html. it should be one aggrid only based on if conditions it is going to execute one aggrid. Before i created only one ag-grid in my html, but now i tried with 3 ag-grids with different if conditions in my custom-ag-grid. so i didn't expect this answer.

Comment: Then you may need to put this in one generic component and have parameters (@input, @output) for dynamic ag attributes and pass it from the place where you call it. Like I’d, rowsata and etc. That will solve requirement!

Comment: You don't need to use hashtag binding `# +  @ViewChild('...') ...;` if you have defined `onGridReady` function for API reference binding.

Comment: @un.spike Thank you for the mention. I have updated your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

customaggrid.html

```
<div [ngStyle]="style">
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" #agGrid class="ag-theme-blue" 
 [rowData]="rowData" rowSelection="single"
 [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [pagination]="pagination" [enableSorting]="enableSorting" 
 [enableColResize]="enableColResize"
 (input)="dataChange($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
 (getSelectedRows)="getSelectedRows()" (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
 </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Before my customaggrid.html is this one, for executing my output purpose i created 3 ag-grids in my customaggrid.html in the top question. i expecting different answer form you(RajeshKdev).

Comment: From Your question what I understood is if you initialise 3 only one works and not other two ag grid. Hence provided the answer earlier. :) You have to use components for this purpose and you can reuse it.

Comment: What your trying to say is in single component it won't work,  so i have create 3 components for 3 ag-grids right.... if i try like this means ...may be it will work

Comment: I think that with single component it will work, you just need to call multiple times based on your condition. Along with different parameters that changes control identity, data and styles (As per your requirement). Those are the parameters which would become as `@input, @output` in the single component. Simple you will call three times instead of three ag-grids.